# Codeigniter - uri segment

Tags: codeigniter, controller

i need to create an url like this: www.example.com/index.php/scheda/name-surname-id.html

so i create the Scheda controller, this is the code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Scheda extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        $name_scheda = $this->uri->segment(2);
        //i need only the id for the search into db
        $id = substr($name_scheda, strripos($name_scheda,'-')+1, strlen($name_scheda));

        echo "name:".$id;
    }
}
```

but when i write the url in the address bar i get an `404 error`...can someone help me to understand why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your url:

```
www.example.com/index.php/scheda/name-surname-id.html
```

Should be:

```
www.example.com/index.php/scheda/index/name-surname-id.html
```

`index()` is the default method, but the `index` segment can only be missing from the URL if there are no arguments, otherwise Codeigniter will think you are trying to call the method `name-surname-id.html()`.

You can use [`routes.php`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) or [`_remap()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) to clean up the URL and remove the `index` segment.

```
// routes.php
$routes['scheda/(:any)'] = 'scheda/index/$1';
```

OR:

```
class Scheda extends CI_Controller{

    function _remap($method, $args) {
        $name_scheda = $method;
        $id = substr($name_scheda, strripos($name_scheda,'-')+1, strlen($name_scheda));
        echo "name:".$id;
    }
}
```